# Фриз кнопки android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

я новичок в программировании. Изучаю Java, android разработку. Недавно я начал писать простое приложение-викторину. Я столкнулся с проблемой которую никак не могу решить. Суть заключается в фризе, из которого нельзя выйти. Это происходит при нажатии на кнопку. Прикрепляю архив с проектом и видео фриза. Так-же этот фриз происходит только при умножении или делении и тд(6-16 лвла).
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZJOlEmmpCHBzsil2bA55-U1O_9Oq-DPK
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ot_bdciwOnKeC4REXDC_jW7uvztJgAkC

Вот код 16 уровня

```
public class Level16 extends AppCompatActivity {


    public int count = 0;
    Dialog dialog, dialogEnd, dialogLose;
    private long backPressedTime;
    private Toast backToast;
    public int numLeft, numRight, numLeft1, numRight1, numLeft2, numRight2, numLeftS, numLeft1n, numRightS, numRight1n; //переменные для кнопок
    Random random = new Random();
    Button btr, btl;
    public ProgressBar pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.universal);


        pb = findViewById(R.id.pBar);

        final CountDownTimer tillTheEnd = new CountDownTimer(35000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                pb.setMax(35);
                pb.setProgress((int)(millisUntilFinished/1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                dialogLose.show();
            }
        }.start();

        final int[] progress = {
                R.id.p1, R.id.p2, R.id.p3, R.id.p4, R.id.p5,
                R.id.p6, R.id.p7, R.id.p8, R.id.p9, R.id.p10,
                R.id.p11, R.id.p12, R.id.p13, R.id.p14, R.id.p15
        };

        final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Level16.this, R.anim.alpha);

        btl = findViewById(R.id.answ1);
        btr = findViewById(R.id.answ2);

        //начало

        int promL,promR,promM,promB;

        promL = random.nextInt(2);

        if(promL==1){
            numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
            numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1;

            numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
            promM=random.nextInt(1);
            if (promM==1){
                numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
            }else{
                numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
            }
        }else{
            numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
            numLeft1n=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numLeft1n==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
            numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1n;
            numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
            promM=random.nextInt(1);
            if (promM==1){
                numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" + "+numLeft2);
            }else{
                numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" - "+numLeft2);
            }
        }

        promR = random.nextInt(2);

        if(promR==1){
            numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
            numRightS=numRight1*numRight1;

            numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
            promB=random.nextInt(1);
            if (promB==1){
                numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
            }else{
                numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
            }
        }else{
            numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
            numRight1n=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numRight1n==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
            numRightS=numRight1*numRight1n;
            numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
            while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
            promB=random.nextInt(1);
            if (promB==1){
                numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" + "+numRight2);
            }else{
                numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" - "+numRight2);
            }
        }

        while(numLeft==numRight){

            promL = random.nextInt(2);

            if(promL==1){
                numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1;

                numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                promM=random.nextInt(1);
                if (promM==1){
                    numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                    btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                }else{
                    numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                    btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                }
            }else{
                numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                numLeft1n=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numLeft1n==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1n;
                numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                promM=random.nextInt(1);
                if (promM==1){
                    numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                    btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" + "+numLeft2);
                }else{
                    numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                    btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" - "+numLeft2);
                }
            }

            promR = random.nextInt(2);

            if(promR==1){
                numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                numRightS=numRight1*numRight1;

                numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                promB=random.nextInt(1);
                if (promB==1){
                    numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                    btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                }else{
                    numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                    btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                }
            }else{
                numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                numRight1n=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numRight1n==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                numRightS=numRight1*numRight1n;
                numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                promB=random.nextInt(1);
                if (promB==1){
                    numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                    btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" + "+numRight2);
                }else{
                    numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                    btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" - "+numRight2);
                }
            }

        }

        //конец
        btl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                btr.setEnabled(false);
                if(numLeft>numRight){
                    btl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answ);
                    btr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer);

                    if(count<15) count++;
                    try{
                        for (int i=0; i<15; i++){
                            TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_point);
                        } }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("Error is in grey points", "LeftGreyPoints");
                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_progress_point);
                    }
                }else{
                    btr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answ);
                    btl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer);
                    if(count>0) if (count==1) count=0; else count=count-2;
                    try{
                        for (int i=0; i<14; i++){
                            TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_point);
                        } }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("Error is in left grey points 2", "LeftGreyPoints2");
                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_progress_point);
                    }
                }

                if (count == 15){
                    tillTheEnd.cancel();
                    dialogEnd.show();
                    //выход из уровня
                }else{




                    //начало

                    int promL,promR,promM,promB;

                    promL = random.nextInt(2);

                    if(promL==1){
                        numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1;

                        numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promM=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promM==1){
                            numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                        }else{
                            numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                        }
                    }else{
                        numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numLeft1n=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft1n==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1n;
                        numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promM=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promM==1){
                            numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" + "+numLeft2);
                        }else{
                            numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" - "+numLeft2);
                        }
                    }

                    promR = random.nextInt(2);

                    if(promR==1){
                        numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numRightS=numRight1*numRight1;

                        numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promB=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promB==1){
                            numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                        }else{
                            numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                        }
                    }else{
                        numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numRight1n=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight1n==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numRightS=numRight1*numRight1n;
                        numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promB=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promB==1){
                            numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" + "+numRight2);
                        }else{
                            numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" - "+numRight2);
                        }
                    }

                    while(numLeft==numRight){

                        promL = random.nextInt(2);

                        if(promL==1){
                            numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1;

                            numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promM=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promM==1){
                                numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                            }else{
                                numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                            }
                        }else{
                            numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numLeft1n=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft1n==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1n;
                            numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promM=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promM==1){
                                numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" + "+numLeft2);
                            }else{
                                numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" - "+numLeft2);
                            }
                        }

                        promR = random.nextInt(2);

                        if(promR==1){
                            numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numRightS=numRight1*numRight1;

                            numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promB=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promB==1){
                                numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                            }else{
                                numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                            }
                        }else{
                            numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numRight1n=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight1n==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numRightS=numRight1*numRight1n;
                            numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promB=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promB==1){
                                numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" + "+numRight2);
                            }else{
                                numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" - "+numRight2);
                            }
                        }

                    }


                    //конец



                    btl.startAnimation(a);
                    btr.startAnimation(a);
                    btr.setEnabled(true);
                }
                btl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_btn_stroke);
                btr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_btn_stroke);
            }catch (Exception e){}
            }
        });



        btr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                btl.setEnabled(false);
                if(numRight>numLeft){
                    btr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answ);
                    btl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer);

                    if(count<15) count++;
                    try{
                        for (int i=0; i<15; i++){
                            TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_point);
                        } }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("Error is in right grey points", "RightGreyPoints");
                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_progress_point);
                    }

                }else {
                    btl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answ);
                    btr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer);
                    if(count>0) if (count==1) count=0; else count=count-2;

                    try{
                        for (int i=0; i<14; i++){
                            TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_point);
                        } }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("Error is in right grey points 2", "RightGreyPoints2");
                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                        TextView tv = findViewById(progress[i]);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_progress_point);
                    }

                }

                if (count == 15){
                    tillTheEnd.cancel();
                    dialogEnd.show();
                    //выход из уровня
                }else{


                    //начало

                    int promL,promR,promM,promB;

                    promL = random.nextInt(2);

                    if(promL==1){
                        numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1;

                        numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promM=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promM==1){
                            numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                        }else{
                            numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                        }
                    }else{
                        numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numLeft1n=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft1n==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1n;
                        numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promM=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promM==1){
                            numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" + "+numLeft2);
                        }else{
                            numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                            btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" - "+numLeft2);
                        }
                    }

                    promR = random.nextInt(2);

                    if(promR==1){
                        numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numRightS=numRight1*numRight1;

                        numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promB=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promB==1){
                            numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                        }else{
                            numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                        }
                    }else{
                        numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numRight1n=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight1n==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                        numRightS=numRight1*numRight1n;
                        numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                        promB=random.nextInt(1);
                        if (promB==1){
                            numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" + "+numRight2);
                        }else{
                            numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                            btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" - "+numRight2);
                        }
                    }

                    while(numLeft==numRight){

                        promL = random.nextInt(2);

                        if(promL==1){
                            numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1;

                            numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promM=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promM==1){
                                numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                            }else{
                                numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                            }
                        }else{
                            numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numLeft1n=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft1n==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft1==0) numLeft1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numLeftS=numLeft1*numLeft1n;
                            numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numLeft2==0) numLeft2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promM=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promM==1){
                                numLeft=numLeftS+numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" + "+numLeft2);
                            }else{
                                numLeft=numLeftS-numLeft2;
                                btl.setText(numLeft1+"×"+numLeft1n+" - "+numLeft2);
                            }
                        }

                        promR = random.nextInt(2);

                        if(promR==1){
                            numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numRightS=numRight1*numRight1;

                            numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promB=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promB==1){
                                numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " + " + numLeft2);
                            }else{
                                numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1 + "²" + " - " + numLeft2);
                            }
                        }else{
                            numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numRight1n=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight1n==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight1==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);
                            numRightS=numRight1*numRight1n;
                            numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            while(numRight2==0) numRight2=random.nextInt(3);
                            promB=random.nextInt(1);
                            if (promB==1){
                                numRight=numRightS+numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" + "+numRight2);
                            }else{
                                numRight=numRightS-numRight2;
                                btr.setText(numRight1+"×"+numRight1n+" - "+numRight2);
                            }
                        }

                    }



                    //конец



                    btl.startAnimation(a);
                    btr.startAnimation(a);
                    btl.setEnabled(true);
                }

                btl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_btn_stroke);
                btr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_btn_stroke);
            }catch (Exception e){}}

        });

    }
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код 11 уровня (или любого другого, который есть в видео с фризом). Лазить по архиву всем лень будет, а ошибка, скорее всего, будет очевидная

Comment: Как минимум вот это вызывает зависание в каждом третьем случае `while(numRight1n==0) numRight1=random.nextInt(3);` уверен, это не единственное место. Вам надо ооооочень сильно перерабатывать код, то, что сейчас - ужас какой-то

Comment: Ахахах, у Вас эта строчка 5 раз встречается в коде) Почитайте о том, что такое методы и функции. И научитесь их использовать. Копировать и вставлять код - это прям очень плохо!

Comment: Я половину стер, тк не помещалось

Comment: У Вас вообще весь код записан в одном методе, не делайте так, пожалуйста! Если у Вас метод занимает более 15 строк - это уже очень-очень плохо, идеально 5-6 строк и меньше. Перепишите все на маленькие методы. У Вас резко уменьшится в размерах и станет очень простым.

Comment: Спасибо за совет насчет функции, своим высокомерным поведением насчет кода ты кончено не помог, но с функцией очень хорошая мысль)

Comment: И если можешь, то пожалуйста расскажи о разбивании кода на мелкие методы, заранее спасибо

Comment: Могу посоветовать почитать книгу чистая архитектура. Она во многом про то, чего Вам не хватает. Если вкратце, то определите похожие (почти одинаковые) куски кода. И сделайте так, чтобы заменить их на вызов какого-то метода. У Васк код будет написан только один раз и много раз вызван одной строчкой.

Comment: Ок, большое спасибо